# Is it possible to have a transparent background?

Tags: jquery, html, css, transparency, transparent

I'd like to have the users desktop or whatever windows they have open show through the background with a slight bit of opacity. I did a quick mockup in photoshop to try and illustrate what I'm aiming for

I'm fine with using a bit of jQuery if need be, but would prefer to keep the foot print light. I don't really want to add a ton of overhead just for a fancy effect.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the cool idea :-)

Comment: If you have control over your end user's computers, then you can create a browser that supports that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term is `Form Opacity`, and you have to have access to the applications source code, in most cases to manipulate it. Several programs already have this as a standard or hidden feature, i.e. Trillian, and iCalenderLite, to name a couple.... Windows 7 allows you to do it to any open window.

[form.opacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

EDIT: Answer has been getting downvoted without comment, so I added the OP's and my additional remarks here.

Would this still be out of bounds for a website to change though? FREX I couldn't have my website turn form opacity on (just for site X) if it wasn't already? – aslum Jun 7 '11 at 23:33

For that, I would have to say "not possible", unless it was a "live" control, loaded by the browser to begin with. You most likely would not be able to do it on a "by site" basis only. And even though most user initiated events are "technically" replicable via script or code, proper security levels, would render such an event, inaccessible to outside manipulation. – tahwos Jun 8 '11 at 22:04

Comment: Would this still be out of bounds for a website to change though? FREX I couldn't have my website turn form opacity on (just for site X) if it wasn't already?

Comment: For that, I would have to say "not possible", unless it was a "live" control, loaded by the browser to begin with. You most likely would not be able to do it on a "by site" basis only. And even though most user initiated events are "technically" replicable via script or code, proper security levels, would render such an event, inaccessible to outside manipulation.

Answer (score 10):

No. You cannot make the browser window translucent.

Answer (score 9):

This is completely impossible... using current APIs. It's theoretically possible that one might be implemented in the future, but for now, the best you can do is transparency to the user desired color.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt this is possible since it requires the actual browser window to be transparent, which is almost surely not the case.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is impossible.

99.99% of the time, if you've never seen it before, there's a good reason*.

***EDIT:**  These comments are specific to **web programming**... not meant to apply to the sum total of human innovation.

Comment: I'd have to strongly disagree with this. Until the first time it's done EVERYTHING has never been seen before. You are suggesting that innovation is good only once in ten thousand times.

Comment: @aslum:  Not exactly.  Transparent windows already exist.  I'm suggesting that some things are intentionally engineered to be beyond YOUR (the webmaster's) control.

Comment: @Sparky: There are plenty of things that WE (the webmasters) can do that we shouldn't (FREX Tables for page-layout). Just because it's not possible doesn't mean the lack of option was an intentional design choice. Before CSS tables were about the only way to have a multi-column layout.

Comment: @aslum: Don't make this about innovations in web programming.  To do what you suggest is way **way WAY** outside of anything like that.

Comment: @Sparky: What would you call it then? Maybe it's not something you think is worthwhile. Before Mosaic you couldn't play sound on the internet. If everyone had your attitude there'd be no Youtube. I'm not saying my idea is a great innovation, or even really more than something that might be a little nifty, but it is something that would expand the options available and not inherently a *bad thing* as you seem to be suggesting.

Comment: @aslum:  Oh please.  When did I say this was a "bad idea"?  Stop putting words in my mouth and being so dramatically defensive about it.  My comments were very simple and direct... read them again, but this time, only read what I wrote and not what you think is between the lines.

Comment: @aslum:  The _"good reason"_ is that the programmers of Safari, Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Flock, Explorer, etc. simply do not allow that kind of tinkering with the browser application itself.  Get it now?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with some plugin for the browser, but not by code in your website.

Comment: Could you elaborate, I don't understand.

Comment: Sure. What I'm trying to say is that you want to modify the browser window itself, and not the web page. Therefore, I believe the only way to achieve that effect, is to use a browser plugin. But that isn't what you're asking for, since you want it to be a part of your site.

Comment: @aslum sorry I missed the 'not', I understand if you were confused.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing a lot of this is impossible. The correct answer is currently mostly impossible ;) Using programming, you can create a window or application that is transparent. I have never done anything of the sort, but I have used several programs that allow you to control transparency.

My best bet for controlling opacity of a window is DirectX. So If you were to make a browser with DirectX, you could control the opacity of the window by reading the CSS.

So basicly, you could do it your self, much like mozilla firefox reads their own css (-moz-radius) just make your own DirectX based Web browser. I could see someone getting a lot of support on a project like that.